# Objective-C -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]' for UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have one table view with two sections in both sections I have placed UITextField. But when I am using tag for every textField it was sharing same tag for both section and because of that my app is crashing. If 1st section contain 4 TextField and 2nd one is about 2 TextField.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if (Array1) {
        [Array1 setObject:textField.text atIndexedSubscript:[textField tag]-1];
        NSLog(@"Array1 after edit: %@",Array1);
    }

    if (Array2) {

        [Array2 setObject:textField.text atIndexedSubscript:[textField tag]-1]; // app crashing at this line
        NSLog(@"Array2 after edit: %@",Array2);
    } 
}
```

It gives this Error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM setObject:atIndex:]: index 2 beyond
>   bounds [0 .. 0]'
>
> *** First throw call stack:

my taleView code like this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;    //count of section
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
         if (section == 0 ) {
            return [Array1 count];
        } else {
            return [Array2 count];
        }
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell=(CustomCell *)[ProfileTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomeCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
    [cell.SInfoTxt setPlaceholder:[[ProfileTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"FN"]];
    cell.SInfoTxt.text=[Array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {
    [cell.SInfoTxt setPlaceholder:[[profileTblCustomArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"FN"]];
    cell.SInfoTxt.text=[Array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    cell.SInfoTxt.tag=indexPath.row+1;

    //set cell background clear color
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How and where you initialised Array1 and Array2 ? Are you setting nil to those array from anywhere in the code ?

Comment: i have initialise Array1 and Array2 as NSMutableArray in my .h file and when am enter any text it gets that txt and shows in my textfiled only when i click 1st, 2nd, 3rd  UITextFiled  in this sequence and but if i click any random textfield it crash...and  i am not added all my code in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using tag in `UITextfield` delegate, you could using its frame origin to know its cell indexPath.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGPoint origin = textField.frame.origin;
    CGPoint point = [textField convertPoint:origin toView:self.tableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];

    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        [Array1 setObject:textField.text atIndexedSubscript:[textField tag]-1];
        NSLog(@"Array1 after edit: %@",Array1);
    }

    if (indexPath.section==1) {
        [Array2 setObject:textField.text atIndexedSubscript:[textField tag]-1]; 
        NSLog(@"Array2 after edit: %@",Array2);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in this code

```
cell.SInfoTxt.text=[Array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.SInfoTxt.text=[Array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

if you have different total of object each array.

you must set different count in this delegate method -numberOfRowsInSection

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return [Array1 count ];
    } else {
        return [Array2 count];
    }
} i have set this

Comment: cell.SInfoTxt.tag=indexPath.row+1;   this is common tag for both section how can i create two different tag for two section...

Comment: both ProfileTableArray and profileTblCustomArray  have equal total of object same Array1,Array2 ?

Comment: if Array1 have 4 value but ProfileTableArray have 2 value , you set numberofRowinSection with [Array1 count]  when loop to index 3  but ProfileTableArray have only 2 value ,it can occur same your error now.

Comment: they are same number of object in array1 and ProfileTableArray... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your have two arrays for two section. So you may be have different count in the arrays. Better you use like this.

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
         if (section == 0 ) {
            return [Array1 count];
        } else {
            return [Array2 count];
        }
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        CustomCell *cell=(CustomCell *)[ProfileTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
            if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomeCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        if (indexPath.section==0) {
            [cell.SInfoTxt setPlaceholder:[[ProfileTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"FN"]];
            cell.SInfoTxt.text=[Array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.SInfoTxt.tag=1000+indexPath.row; // We can easily identifies using tag.

        } else {
            [cell.SInfoTxt setPlaceholder:[[profileTblCustomArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"FN"]];
            cell.SInfoTxt.text=[Array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.SInfoTxt.tag=2000+indexPath.row;

        }

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: yes i have already write this is my code...and am  not posted all my code... actually i am facing problem with tag.  
cell.SInfoTxt.tag=indexPath.row+1; this is common tag for both section how can i create two different tag for two section

Comment: All Views are on default tag value 0 as tag value. So try another tag value.

Don't use same tag value for all subview. Please use it like this.
if(section == 0)
    cell.SInfoTxt.tag = 1000 + indexPath.row;
else
   cell.SInfoTxt.tag = 2000 + indexPath.row;

Comment: ok and in - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField should i only use [textField tag] or something else

Comment: If you don't increase value in cell.SInfoTxt.tag=2000+indexPath.row. you can you use  if([textfield tag] >= 2000)int tagvalue= [textfield tag]-2000 else  int tagvalue= [textfield tag]-1000